# Insert row without modifying a range - GOOGLE SHEETS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there any way to do this? with the button (+) I show a prompt where I select the number of row I want to add (in this example, the purple and green rectangles). What I want is that the blue square never deforms and the text that has inside neither, is there some way to do it?

[Link to a image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wosT3.png)

Comment: what do you want to add? you did say columns, but do you means rows or cells instead? Insert 'columns' into purple and green area without deforming the blue area seems to be physically impossible to me.

Comment: I think setValues() will do that for you as long as you maintaina minimum of about 30 rows

Comment: yes , im misspelled , @silbido you are right

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through the parameter [`WrapStrategy`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#WrapStrategy). [Here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells) is the link of reference to all the changes you can make for a cell.

Here is more of the overall JSON format:

```
{
  "spreadsheetId": string,
  "properties": {
      "title": string,
      "locale": string,
      "autoRecalc": enum (RecalculationInterval),
      "timeZone": string,
      "defaultFormat": {
/*          "numberFormat": {
              object (NumberFormat)
          },
          "backgroundColor": {
              object (Color)
          },
          "backgroundColorStyle": {
              object (ColorStyle)
          },
          "borders": {
              object (Borders)
          },
          "padding": {
              object (Padding)
          },
          "horizontalAlignment": enum (HorizontalAlign),
          "verticalAlignment": enum (VerticalAlign),*/
          "wrapStrategy": enum (WrapStrategy),
/*        "textDirection": enum (TextDirection),
          "textFormat": {
              object (TextFormat)
          },
          "hyperlinkDisplayType": enum (HyperlinkDisplayType),
          "textRotation": {
              object (TextRotation)
          }*/
      },
/*    "iterativeCalculationSettings": {
          object (IterativeCalculationSettings)
      },
      "spreadsheetTheme": {
          object (SpreadsheetTheme)
      }*/
  },
  "sheets": [
      {
          object (Sheet)
      }
  ],
  "namedRanges": [
    {
      object (NamedRange)
    }
  ],
  "spreadsheetUrl": string,
  "developerMetadata": [
    {
      object (DeveloperMetadata)
    }
  ],
  "dataSources": [
    {
      object (DataSource)
    }
  ],
  "dataSourceSchedules": [
    {
      object (DataSourceRefreshSchedule)
    }
  ]
}
```